# Assign Different Value and Text to Dropdown List Items

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, drop-down-menu, code-behind

I am trying to populate a dropdown list on pageload with data from the batabase.

While populating I want the dropdown items (`<option>`) to have the display text which is different from '`value`' of the `<option>`

For example: The dropdown list will show "Title" (column from db) as text on UI, but the '`value`' of the `<option>` should be "ID" (column from db)

How do I achieve this?

Currently my code is like this: (`drpReleaseTitle` is the ID of the dropdown)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        con1.Open();

        SqlCommand releaseTitlecmd = new SqlCommand("select Title from LWMDemo_ReleaseInfo order by ReleaseID", con1);
        SqlDataReader releaseTitledr = releaseTitlecmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (releaseTitledr.Read())
        {
            drpReleaseTitle.Items.Add(releaseTitledr.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
        con1.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
drpReleaseTitle.Items.Add(new ListItem("yourtext", "yourvalue"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to Use Dataset Instead of Data Reader Because it use disconnected  architecture so You can Use After Close the connection

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        con1.Open();

        SqlCommand releaseTitlecmd = new SqlCommand("select Title from LWMDemo_ReleaseInfo order by ReleaseID", con1);
       SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = Cmd;
        sda.Fill(ds);
        if(ds!=null && ds.table.count>0){
        if(ds.table[0]!=null && ds.table[0].rows.count>0){
            drpReleaseTitle.DataSource=ds.table[0].Title;  //Title Column
             drpReleaseTitle.DataSourceID=ds.table[0].ID;  //ID Column
        }
    }
        con1.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will try add a string to Items in drop down list, it will create a item, that will have text and value as your string. You need to add new ListItem. ListItem contains constructor with text and value as parameters. More about this class you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)